# What's the standard practice for deprecating a WCF service call?

Tags: wcf, deprecated

I have a client/server system where one of the wrongly named service calls on the server needs to be deprecated and replaced with the new, better named call.  Is there some standard procedure to deprecate the old service call such as logging it's usage or returning a fault exception or something?

thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not rename it. You should mark it as obsolete with the following attribute:

```
[Obsolete("This is a message describing why this method is obsolete")]
```

and indicate what is the newer method to call.

By doing this, any clients still using this will continue to function.

It's worth noting that this attribute will hide properties/methods from the service metadata, so any client/consumer who creates or updates a reference to this service will lose the property/method completely and be forced not to use it.

Comment: I guess I didn't mean rename.  We created a better named service call and left the old one there.

Comment: In this case just mark the old method as obsolete and maybe change implementation to point to the new code (if there actually is some new code). But don;t change the method signature.

Comment: Be aware that the ObsoleteAttribute does not affect the client proxy classes generated by Visual Studio (I would guess that's also true of those generated by SvcUtil.exe). I.E. It doesn't provide your clients with any indication that the method is deprecated.